# In css grid, some items work and others spill out seemingly at random

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

```css
html {
font-size: 62.5%;
}

.services__header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8rem 0 3rem;
    
}
.services {
    padding-bottom: 10rem;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba($blue-light-2, 0.8),
     rgba(#94B9BE, 0.8)),url("../img/woodbg4.jpg");
    margin-top: -3rem;
    
   
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
   
}

.services__container {
    display: grid;
    margin: 5rem 5rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 5rem;
    
  

  
   
   
    
}

.service {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    
    border: 1px solid #94B9BE;
    }

.service__img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        
        
    }

 .service__title {
        padding: 1rem;
        //background-color: $beige-gold;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        border-radius: 4px;
        //transform: translateY(-2rem);
        
   

}
```

```html
<div class="services" id="services">
            <h2 class="services__header">Our Services</h2>
            <div class="services__container">
            <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/surgery.png" alt="surgical derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-cancer.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Skin Cancer Care</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
               
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="medical derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-medical.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Medical Dermatology</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="laser procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-laser.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Laser Services and Skincare</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="cosmetic derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-cosmetic.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Cosmetic Dermatology</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="acne procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-acne.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Acne</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="cosmetic derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-surgical.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Surgical Dermatology</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
                
        </div><!-- END SERVICES -->
```

[This is what it looks like on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wa9Q.jpg)

[2] I have tried changing up the grid inside each service box, getting rid of the grid, using flexbox, but before only Firefox would render it at all correctly, and then I got rid of the divs and Chrome and Safari are working, except for this random overflow. Changing the image doesn't help, either. Please help!

This is the html code - it repeats like this for six identical :

```
      <div class="services" id="services">
            <h2 class="services__header">Our Services</h2>
            <div class="services__container">
            <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/surgery.png" alt="surgical derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-cancer.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Skin Cancer Care</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>

                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/service2.png" alt="medical derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-medical.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Medical Dermatology</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="laser procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-laser.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Laser Services and Skincare</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/hydrafacial.png" alt="cosmetic derm procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-cosmetic.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Cosmetic Dermatology</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <img src="img/surgery.png" alt="acne procedure" class="service__img"><a href="service-acne.php" class="unstyle">
                    <h3 class="service__title">Acne</h3>
                    <p class="service__content">We apply systems, incentives, and science in order to give you the information to improve medical plans and assist our patients in creating a support system to facilitate a collaborate process designed to incorporate medical, social, and health conditions more effectively.</p>
</a>
```

---

This is the scss code:

````
.services__header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8rem 0 3rem;

}
.services {
    padding-bottom: 10rem;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba($blue-light-2, 0.8),
     rgba($blue-light-2, 0.8)),url("../img/woodbg4.jpg");
    margin-top: -3rem;


    background-attachment: fixed;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}

.services__container {
    display: grid;
    margin: 5rem 5rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 5rem;


}


.service {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 1.5rem;

    border: 1px solid $blue-light-2;

    &:hover {
        background-color: $stone-grey;
        cursor: pointer;

    }
    &__img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;





    }

    &__title {
        padding: 1rem;

        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        border-radius: 4px;



    }


}```
````

Comment: Can you put up a working code snippet illustrating the issue ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak I tried to put up a working code snippet, but the problem isn't occurring like it does on the webpage. I think because the images aren't there. I'm working on adding them, but not sure how to put them in the code snippet.

Comment: That's what I thought, because I tan the code  with random images and it worked as expected, just use images of the same size.

Comment: @ZohirSalak It seems to work no matter what image I put in there, but doesn't work when I change the title text. Then either the grid of the one object breaks or all of the others do. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZohirSalak could it have something to do with the link placement?

Comment: I couldn't say because i don't really know what the issue is.